# Errors using rspec, missing libraries after installing Homebrew and uninstalling MacPorts

Tags: nokogiri, rsync, macports, homebrew, libiconv

I may have taken one step too far beyond my knowledge. I installed [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29) and after it continued to give me warnings about having [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) installed I uninstalled that. But now my rspec tests don't run.

These are the errors I get:

```
/Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri.rb:13:in `require': dlopen(/Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Reason: Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0 - /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
.....
.....
```

I've installed libiconv through Homebrew, but that didn't fix it. It's complaining about libiconv version numbers. Is this the problem?

What is going on here and what do I need to do?

Comment: Where are libiconv*.dylib installed and what version numbers are in their names

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I got things working again for anyone interested. I removed and re-installed nokogiri gem and everything seems to be working again.

Comment: Encountered this exact problem today.

Comment: Same problem here. everything seems to be working again after reinstalling. Thanks!

Comment: I created a new gemset with RVM and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: removing and installing fixed the problem. but I'd still like to thanks Nicholas for his detailed instructions

Answer (score 15):

Generally, **this problem is caused by being unable to find the right libiconv**. Here is how I solve my problem:

Check output of `otool -L /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib`. I got the following output:

```
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Then I install libiconv with Homebrew, `brew install libiconv`, and show where it was installed using `brew list libiconv`. I got the following output:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/bin/iconv
/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/libcharset.1.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/ (3 other files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/share/doc/ (6 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/share/man/ (6 files)
```

the libiconv is installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/libiconv.2.dylib`. Then I check verion of newly installed libiconv,
`otool -L /usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/libiconv.2.dylib`, and I got the following output:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/libiconv.2.dylib:
/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

The version is correct, and we need to make this library available for [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29). Creating a symbol link is a quick solution:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/libiconv.2.dylib /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
```

Comment: I think you can replace the last step by: `brew link --force libiconv`       Anyhow, your answer is a very nice solution since it doesn't involve reinstalling nokogiri.

Comment: Thanks for this! Helped me immensely! I'm not sure for everyone, but I needed to add `brew tap homebrew/dupes` before brew found the `libiconv` formula.

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-install libxml-ruby in addition to nokogiri to get things working again.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I ran into the same issue and if you are **vendorizing your gems, you will have to remove the offending gem from vendor/ruby** as a gem uninstall + reinstall is not always efficient. I'm guessing bundler leaves cache remnants of gems and their respective libs even when running a fresh install.